# Files served via jQuery interpreted as txt/blob instead of their correct file type

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, xmlhttprequest, blob

I am running an AJAX script to serve different kinds of files (.txt/.msg but also images and PDFs). In short, the window pops up, retrieves the file, closes itself again, quite basic:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../myUrl/myFile.msg',
        method: 'GET',
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'myFile.msg';
            a.click();
            a.target='_self';
            setTimeout(function(){    
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);                
                window.close();
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is, that serving .msg files (created by MS Outlook) through this function are treated as blob:// resources - so if our (lazy) users want to open their .msg file right away through firefox, their text editor opens and they get a nice load of encoded string garbage.

I am unsure if this is an Outlook/.msg-specific problem, and I am also unsure if this is a problem with Firefox only (Chrome simply downloads the file).

Is there any way to let the browser know, that the sent file is a .msg file, which should be treated by Outlook and not by the text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overriding the xhr content type you should be able to trigger the right application to open. Try adding this to your ajax call:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
  xhr.overrideMimeType('application/vnd.ms-outlook');
}
```

Actually all this seems to do (in Firefox) is removing the assumed default xml type, and using the file extension to determine which application to use. For that matter you can also use `application/*` or even just `*` in the override.

Comment: This does the trick - thanks a lot. I found a list of MIME types here: https://www.lifewire.com/file-extensions-and-mime-types-3469109 ... maybe this can be of use for someone else.